# How do I simplify this?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm new to JS, and I'm self-learning. I'd like to know how do I simplify this? This kind of block is repeated too many times in my script.

```
$('.itemlist').on('focus', 'textarea.remarks', function (){
        $(this).animate({height: '50px'},400);});
$('.itemlist').on('blur', 'textarea.remarks', function (){
        $(this).animate({height: '15px'},400);});
```

Cheers.

Comment: Show us at least one or two other cases where a similar block of code appears. It's hard to tell you how to simplify it without seeing more examples of similar code.

Comment: try always re-use the jquery selector, by saving them or direct chaining

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could also do something like this:

```
$('.itemlist').on({
    focus: function(){
        $(this).animate({ height: '50px' }, 400);
    },
    blur: function(){
        $(this).animate({ height: '15px' }, 400);
    }
}, 'textarea.remarks');
```

Not to say that it is any simpler, but it looks pretty.  :)

Comment: The prettiest solution. Thanks a lot! I've learned a new way of writing it today thanks to you.

Answer (score 3):

Try it like,

```
var height='50px';
$('.itemlist').on('focus blur', 'textarea.remarks', function (){
    $(this).animate({height: height},400);
    height=(height=='50px') ? '15px' : '50px';
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Maybe something like:

```
$('.itemlist').on('focusin focusout', 'textarea.remarks', function(evt)
{
    var px = 0;

    if(evt.type === 'focusin') px = 50;
    if(evt.type === 'focusout') px = 15;

    $(this).animate({ height: px }, 400);

});
```

Update: Using `focusin` and `focusout` in light of information in the comments below.

Comment: @rolodex Did you add `evt` as the first argument of the callback function?

Comment: @rolodex Also, (in Chrome using jQuery 2.0.2, at least) `evt.type` is `focusin` and `focusout` not `focus` and `blur`.

Comment: @Joe AH, that's interesting. I'll accommodate that.

Comment: @Joe Where do you see that? Did you test that or make that up? I don't see that happening. And I doubt jQuery would allow for such a thing to happen, when you don't specifically bind to `focusin` and `focusout`. http://jsfiddle.net/YTzHz/ . If you actually see that happening, it's a bug, and should be reported to jQuery

Comment: @Ian Lol I try not to just make things up.  It looks like `evt.type` evaluates to `focusin` and `focusout` in this scenario:  http://jsfiddle.net/YTzHz/2/.  Maybe it is a bug.

Comment: @Joe Haha I see. Well that's very interesting! I guess that "makes sense", because the `focus` event doesn't technically bubble (with event delegation, like your example), so it looks like jQuery provides the "correct" event name. I guess it's my fault I never knew this because I've never found the need to check the `event.type` before :) I'm not sure if it's a bug, but I'm not sure I've seen documentation on this happening. I'll have to look...

Comment: @Joe Near the bottom of the `.on()` docs: `The focus and blur events are specified by the W3C to not bubble, but jQuery defines cross-browser focusin and focusout events that do bubble. When focus and blur are used to attach delegated event handlers, jQuery maps the names and delivers them as focusin and focusout respectively. For consistency and clarity, use the bubbling event type names.` - which means that if you're using event delegation with `focus`, you should use `focusin` to bind to. But obviously it works either way, and it really only affects if you're checking `event.type`

Comment: Well, all this information ruins my already below average answer.

Comment: @MartyWallace Why does it ruin it?! I think it helped clear up the correct `evt.type` to check! When using event delegation, you should use/check for `focusin` and `focusout`. I think the way you check for `event.type` was the straightforward way to simplify the handlers into one

Comment: @Ian I moreso meant that the main nicety in my answer was readability, but using `focusin` and `focusout` breaks the obvious relationship between the `on()` statement and its handler's content.

Comment: @MartyWallace I agree.  I think that your solution is really clean.  I might make it much more terse like so:  http://jsfiddle.net/YTzHz/3/.  :)

Comment: @MartyWallace Well the point is that you should also be **bind** ing to `focusin` and `focusout`. So it should be `.on("focusin focusout", func`, which is what jQuery suggests using for event delegation. It obviously works either way because jQuery normalizes bubbling, but they suggest using the "correct" event types. So technically, it should be a suggestion/comment to the OP to use these instead of `focus` and `blur` anyways

Comment: This has been a useful discussion. Thank you guys.